# Ubuntu Server 18.04 kernel panic on Linux 4.15.x kernel

Tags: 18.04, kernel, lts

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 Server then upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and then to the latest LTS version of Ubuntu 18.04 Server.

Updates changed the running kernel version too. Now my computer has two Linux kernels, 4.15.0-43 generic and 4.4.0-141-generic. The first option is 4.15.x and it's stuck at a kernel panic if it is selected.

Here are screenshots of the error:

[image: Kernel panic on Linux 4.15.0-13 generic kernel]

And here is my installed kernels:

[image: Installed kernels]

Kernel 4.4.0-141 boots successfully. but I'd like to use new version of Linux kernel.

Also there is another issue with Ubuntu 18.10. There was the same error, but after community updated Linux kernel version to 4.18.x the problems were gone.

Comment: The beginnig of the stack trace is missing. Try to scroll up (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60382/how-to-scroll-in-a-terminal-using-keyboard) and post the beginning of the trace

Comment: None of key combinations worked. Maybe cause of It's not a VM?

Comment: You need some why of capturing the beginning of that kernel panic... check if the VM has some means of logging the console output

Comment: It is a real machine not VM. Can I check log files if exist from the working kernel 4.4?

Comment: No. I assume the problem is the root file system. So there is no way for the kernel to write that logfile. Does the 4.15 recovery mode boot?

Comment: Recovery mod is not working too. The same kernel panic.

Comment: Okay... that's not good. That basically means it is most likley not the root-fs, because the recovery mode boots into the initrd image. Just an idea: try to boot a Ubuntu 18.04 live image form USB stick.

Comment: I can boot and work with kernel 4.4.0-141-generic. Working with newer kernel means that I have latest secure and reliable os. Less effected by vulnerabilities. Right? If there is a upgrade to kernel version 4.18.x everything will be fine.

Comment: You can work with the 4.4 until the support is droped in April 2019. In Feb 2019 the new LTS (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) 18.04.02 will be out. It sould contain a Kernel around 4.19...